# Excessive arguments error for recursive reverse string method

Tags: c++, recursion

I'm trying to program a recursive function that prints the reverse of the string, however, the compiler keeps saying it has too many arguments. What is wrong with this recursive program?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void reverseDisplay (const string& s)
{

    int length=s.size()-1;
    if (length==0)
        return;

    reverseDisplay(s, length);
}

void reverseDisplay (const string& s, int n)
{
    if(n==1)
        cout <<s[n];

    else { 
        cout << s[n];
        reverseDisplay(s, n-1);
    }
}

int main()
{
    string s="12345";
    reverseDisplay(s);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And also, the `if` statement in `reverseDisplay (const string& s, int n)` should be `if(n==0)`

Answer (score 5):

Try a forward declaration:

```
void reverseDisplay (const string& s, int n);
```

Put this before `void reverseDisplay (const string& s)`.

Answer (score 2):

You're not really doing recursion in `reverseDisplay(const string& s)`.  You're calling the *other* `reverseDisplay()`, which takes two arguments.  This makes them overloaded, so the compiler will call the one that matches the arguments (or display an error if no such overload exists).

Here's a working recursive solution with just one display function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void reverseDisplay(std::string const& s, std::size_t n)
{
    if (n == -1)
    {
        return;
    }

    std::cout << s[n];
    reverseDisplay(s, n-1);
}

int main()
{
    std::string s = "12345";
    std::size_t size = s.size();
    reverseDisplay(s, size-1);
}
```

Comment: Which should be before the other one, anyway.

Comment: Why use recursion at all for this? Why not use a simple for loop from length - 1 downto 0?

Comment: @KristerAndersson: I wasn't addressing that.  In any event of recursion, the OP's code isn't doing that there.  The `reverseDisplay()` with two arguments is doing this properly, though.

Answer (score 2):

To solve a problem recursively, you want a function that calls itself, and a stopping condition.  Using the size, however, is not necessary.  Also, it will be more useful if you have a method that reverses a string; leave printing for later.  Now, the typical way to reverse a string in any language is this bit of pseudocode:

```
reverse("abcd")            -->
        string suffix
reverse("abcd", ""       ) -->  
reverse("bcd",  "a" + "" ) ==
reverse("bcd",  "a"      ) --> string, suffix
reverse("cd",   "b" + "a") ==
reverse("cd",   "ba"     ) -->
reverse("d",    "c" + "ba")==
reverse("d",    "cba"    ) -->
reverse("", "d" + cba")
reverse("", "dcba")       --> Let this be the stopping condition.
```

So,  we do this:

```
string reverse(const string original, string suffix);

string reverse(const string original) { 
    return reverse(original, new string);
} 

string reverse(const string original, string suffix) { 
    if (original.size()) {
         auto first = original.first();
         return reverse(original.substr(1), suffix.insert(0, 1, first));
    } else {
        return suffix;
    }
}
```

I could probably have made some of these variables references.